# Not able to plot the series type when using python3

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am using Python3 and I got the problem when I have been working on it.
I coded as below and I found the right results that I expected. And then I want to see the result as diagram. So I tried to plot it but I got the unexpected error indicating that I need the matplotlib. Since I imported the matplotlib at the first code, I have no idea solving this issue.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
train.Survived[train['Name']=='Mr'].value_counts()

#Result
0    436
1     81
Name: Survived, dtype: int64
```

I typed the below code to see them as pie-like diagram.

```
train.Survived[train['Name']=='Mr'].value_counts().plot(kind='pie')
```

The error message is as below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-191-7f60a15206ad> in <module>()
      1 import pandas.plotting
----> 2 train.Survived[train['Name']=='Mr'].value_counts().plot(kind='pie')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in __call__(self, kind, ax, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, label, secondary_y, **kwds)
   2739                            colormap=colormap, table=table, yerr=yerr,
   2740                            xerr=xerr, label=label, secondary_y=secondary_y,
-> 2741                            **kwds)
   2742     __call__.__doc__ = plot_series.__doc__
   2743 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in plot_series(data, kind, ax, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, label, secondary_y, **kwds)
   2000                  yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr,
   2001                  label=label, secondary_y=secondary_y,
-> 2002                  **kwds)
   2003 
   2004 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in _plot(data, x, y, subplots, ax, kind, **kwds)
   1757                 data = data[y].copy()
   1758                 data.index.name = y
-> 1759         plot_obj = klass(data, subplots=subplots, ax=ax, kind=kind, **kwds)
   1760     else:
   1761         if isinstance(data, ABCDataFrame):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in __init__(self, data, kind, **kwargs)
   1498         if (data < 0).any().any():
   1499             raise ValueError("{0} doesn't allow negative values".format(kind))
-> 1500         MPLPlot.__init__(self, data, kind=kind, **kwargs)
   1501 
   1502     def _args_adjust(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in __init__(self, data, kind, by, subplots, sharex, sharey, use_index, figsize, grid, legend, rot, ax, fig, title, xlim, ylim, xticks, yticks, sort_columns, fontsize, secondary_y, colormap, table, layout, **kwds)
    105                  table=False, layout=None, **kwds):
    106 
--> 107         _raise_if_no_mpl()
    108         _converter._WARN = False
    109         self.data = data

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in _raise_if_no_mpl()
     55     # TODO(mpl_converter): remove once converter is explicit
     56     if not _HAS_MPL:
---> 57         raise ImportError("matplotlib is required for plotting.")
     58 
     59 

ImportError: matplotlib is required for plotting.
```

I really appreciate it if you could resolve my issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you don't have `matplotlib` installed. You write *"Since I imported the matplotlib at the first code, [...]"*. This is nowhere in the code you added. Please try to be more clear. Also try `pip install matplotlib` and then rerun the code.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Jupyter (I was) and you have `matplotlib` installed and imported correctly, try to restart the kernel in your notebook:

Menu > Kernel > Restart

Then re-run all the needed code. This solved my problem. I got the idea from [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19810#issuecomment-381944921). It looks like other problem with the same solution.

Hope it helps.